# gnuplot: set key on either left or right side based on which axis it is plotting on

Tags: key, gnuplot

I am using both ytics and y2tics as my data ranges are vastly different. By using both axes, all data are proportionally represented. See this sample image:[image: sample image]

The "clusters", "hosts", and "vsan" data uses the y2axis and the rest uses yaxis. How do I move the keys to either top left or top right side (of the graph) based on the axis they are drawn on?

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
set y2tics
set ytics nomirror
plot "data" using 1:2 title "Clusters" linecolor rgb "black" axes x1y2, \
        '' using 1:3 title "Hosts" linecolor rgb "blue" axes x1y2,\
        '' using 1:4 title "vSAN" linecolor rgb "cyan" axes  x1y2,\
    '' using 1:5 title "VMs" linecolor rgb "purple" axes x1y1,\
        '' using 1:6 title "⚫" linecolor rgb "green"  axes x1y1,\
        '' using 1:7 title "⚪" linecolor rgb "red" axes x1y1
```

Here is some sample test data:

```
2016-12-18 22 131 0 1179 1024 155
2016-12-19 22 131 0 1179 1025 154
2016-12-20 22 131 0 1178 1025 153
2016-12-21 22 129 0 1180 1026 154
2016-12-22 22 132 0 1182 1014 168
2016-12-23 22 133 0 1182 1016 166
2016-12-24 22 133 0 1187 1016 171
2016-12-25 22 133 0 1187 1016 171
2016-12-26 22 133 0 1187 1016 171
2016-12-27 22 133 0 1187 1016 171
2016-12-28 22 133 0 1189 1017 172
2016-12-29 22 133 0 1189 1018 171
2016-12-30 22 133 0 1189 1018 171
2017-01-01 22 133 0 1189 1018 171
2017-01-02 22 133 0 1189 1018 171
2017-01-03 22 133 0 1185 1020 165
2017-01-04 22 133 0 1183 1018 165
2017-01-05 22 133 0 1183 1017 166
2017-01-06 22 133 0 1174 1018 156
2017-01-07 22 133 0 1173 1018 155
2017-01-08 22 133 0 1173 1018 155
2017-01-09 22 133 0 1175 1011 164
2017-01-10 22 131 0 1170 1004 166
2017-01-11 22 131 0 1170 1004 166
2017-01-13 22 131 0 1162 998 164
```

Updated sample image based on Maij's answer:

[image]

Comment: Great information.  Could you please show the code that labels the X axis in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "to either left or right side" you mean the sides of the graph area then you can use a `multiplot` environment. We have to adjust the margins manually, and we have to take care that the y-tics are not printed on the wrong side.

```
set samples 1000
set xrange [0:2*pi]

# The plots must overlap, so we set the margins manually.
# We have to play with the numbers, the depend on the terminal.
set lmargin at screen 0.25
set rmargin at screen 0.75

set key outside

set terminal pngcairo size 800,400
set output "two_keys.png"

set multiplot

   # no ytics on the right side for the first plot
   set ytics nomirror
   set key left
   plot sin(x) lt 2, \
        cos(x) lt 3

   # no ytics on the left side for the second plot
   unset ytics
   set y2tics
   set y2range [-10:10]

   set key right
   plot tan(x) axis x1y2 lt 4

unset multiplot
```

This is the result with gnuplot 4.6:[image: plot with two legends]

Comment: Thanks. That works. The outside legend takes up a bit too much room. Is there a way to reserve some room "inside" and squeeze the legends there? I tried to modify the yrange but that seems to throw the charts out of proportion (or the lines are not true to the y numbers).

Comment: @zagpoint 1) You could reduce the space between the key and the plot by setting the key position explicitly with `set key at screen <x>, <y>`. 

2) Setting `yrange` to reserve space inside the plot should work. It might be necessary to set `yrange` and `y2range` for both, the first and the second plot, even while only one of them is used, respectively.

3) If the data allows it, I would explicitly set `yrange`, `y2range`, `ytics`, `y2tics` such that the number of tics on both sides of the plot is equal. Then the ygrid looks better.

Answer (score 1):

If by "to either left or right side" you mean the sides of the legend itself then you can create two-column legend. Since you have six curves, set the parameter `maxrows` to 3, so you will have 3 rows and 2 columns.

```
set term pngcairo size 1024,700
set output 'key.png'
set key right outside maxrows 3
set y2tics
set ytics nomirror
plot sin(x) t '1' axes x1y2,\
2*sin(x) t '2' axes x1y2,\
3*sin(x) t '3' axes x1y2,\
4*sin(x) t '4' axes x1y1,\
5*sin(x) t '5' axes x1y1,\
6*sin(x) t '6' axes x1y1
```

[image]

Comment: I actually meant to say the left/right side of the graph area....I've edited the op to reflect that. Thanks...